# MongoDB connection reset inside Docker swarm mode

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I have a MongoDB database on my server, which runs inside a docker container.
I used to start the container using docker-compose. Recently I updated my docker to 17.03.1-ce and configured swarm mode on it.

Then I ran my mongodb container and tried to perform a large operation (reading ~10000000 collection using cursor) on it from java (using mongodb-async driver, if it matters) and it randomly fails with the message "Connection reset".

I tried to run mongodb by using simple `docker run` and it worked, however when I try to use it inside swarm mode using `docker stack deploy --compose-file ...` this error appeared.
It may appear or may not, ~20% of all my tries tend to be successful.

MongoDB container log says nothing useful, just `end connection` like everything is ok.

Docker is installed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, using official MongoDB image `mongo:3.4`.

Hope anyone could help me. Thanks.